# Linux network authentication issue

Tags: linux, debian, networking

I know this is a lot more on the networking side than it is Linux, but I'm only having this issue on my computer. Everything else connects just fine.

What's going on is I have a router in one room (router A) and I set up a router in another end of my house (router B) that's hardwired into A. A and B have their own SSID's, they're both broadcasting and providing internet just fine to my other devices. Only thing I'm having an issue with is on my Linux system, every time I try to connect wirelessly to either of my two routers it keeps saying it requires authentication, where I'll then enter my password and it'll look like it's accepting it, then it'll ask me for my password again.

Anybody have any idea as to why? Thank you for any help in advanced

Comment: Add the output of `iwlist scan` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if this is not the best answer, but I don't know much about the problem. I have dealt with it too on my Linux Mint when trying to connect to a network secured by WPA Enterprise. I'd recommend two possible solutions to try: First, (though I would assume you've already tried this) reboot your computer. You could also try manually shutting off Wifi and then turning it back on. Second, try deleting the existing connection and its data and save a new connection. That has worked for me, if I'm correct.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why restarting it worked. I had used terminal and the gui to knock out my adapters and turn them back on and everything I was trying wasn't working, then later on I just restarted my computer as a last resort and for whatever reason it worked afterwards. Not sure what the difference was as far as my network settings goes. Curious

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the computer later and for whatever reason, that resolved the issue. I had gone through terminal and set my wireless adapter to down then started it back up, also disabled the Wi-Fi through the gui. Does anyone know why you'd have to restart the system for it to work? What would be the difference between restarting the entire system vs knocking out your Wi-Fi then turning it back on?

Comment: It would be best for you to post this as another question.